# Where does node.js fit in a Microsoft / Azure / WCF / MVC project?

Tags: wcf, model-view-controller, architecture, azure, node.js

I have been working on a real time data project using the Microsoft stack and it seems that node.js is made for this very purpose (of real time data) and is getting a lot of publicity.

- Does it makes sense to integrate node.js into my MSFT solution?  (what criteria should I be considering)
- How does it "hook into" the project?
- What components does it replace?

Comment: Steve Marx of Azure team got it working, you might want to follow up with him and get him to document the experience: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/317e5cd4-dc89-4d01-a19d-1f9a38332c3c/

Comment: Keep in mind that Node.JS has no official support for Windows at the moment. If you plan to use this for production code, I would say don't do it yet.

Comment: This article shows you how you can get node running in Azure: http://coderead.wordpress.com/2011/09/22/windows-azure-and-node-js/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this episode](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Cloud+Cover/Cloud-Cover-Episode-48-Nodejs-Ruby-and-Python-in-Windows-Azure) of Cloud Cover and the [Node.js blog](http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/06/23/porting-node-to-windows-with-microsoft%25e2%2580%2599s-help/) it would appear that Node.js is officially coming to Azure (and probably Windows in general).

Answer (score 2):

Steve Marx demo'd this for http://chat.smarx.com/

You can see the basic code at [http://things.smarx.com/#Run Node.js](http://things.smarx.com/#Run%20Node.js) -

```
  var proc = new Process()
  {
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(
        RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("Executables").RootPath + @"\node.exe",
        string.Format("server.js {0}",
        RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints["HttpIn"].IPEndpoint.Port))
    {
        UseShellExecute = false,
        WorkingDirectory = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("Executables").RootPath
    }
};
```

but I can't currently find a full blog post from him about this

Comment: I don't know if it's (ever) safe to use node.js on windows in production code...i'd rather say "HELL NO".

Answer (score 2):

If you like node, look at Nancy for .NET

http://elegantcode.com/2010/11/28/introducing-nancy-a-lightweight-web-framework-inspired-by-sinatra/

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a series of blog posts about running node.js on Windows Azure a few months ago (http://bit.ly/gxHawS).  However I would offer a similar caveat that while it's theoretically possible, I'm not sure I would recommend it (at this point)...